# How to get the single tap point in iOS voice over mode

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

When I am doing the single tap in iOS voice over mode, it will read the tagged elment, but I want to know the tag point x and y, are there any api to get it?

Comment: You can't get this information from VoiceOver. The APIs don't support it. The closest you could get would be to grab onto the focused element, and understand that somewhere within that rectangle was the last touch point. But, even then, there would be no way to distinguish between elements focused by single touch vs elements focused "focustNext" style sequential navigation (swipe right and swipe left gestures).

Comment: Hi ChrisCM, actually my final purpose is get the line content of user clicks and speak out in voice over mode, do you know how can I achieve this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer can you post an answer and I can accept it

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "line content of user clicks and speak out"???

Comment: If there is a text on screen and user taps on the screen, for example taps a point in line 2, so I want voice over read text in line 2,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get this information from VoiceOver. The APIs don't support it. The closest you could get would be to grab onto the focused element, and understand that somewhere within that rectangle was the last touch point. But, even then, there would be no way to distinguish between elements focused by single touch vs elements focused "focustNext" style sequential navigation (swipe right and swipe left gestures).